# Data segment values corrupting the stack variables

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int *ptr1 = malloc ( 2 );
    int *ptr2 = malloc ( 4 );
    int *ptr3 = malloc ( 16 );

    printf("ptr1    -  %x \n", ptr1);
    printf("ptr2    -  %x \n", ptr2);
    printf("ptr3    -  %x \n", ptr3);

    *ptr1 = 0x1111;
    *ptr2 = 0x2222;
    *ptr3 = 0x3333;
#if 1
    // silent corruption...
    *(ptr1+2) = 0xabcd;
#endif
#if 1
    // corruption
    *(ptr1+3) = 0xbeee;
#endif

     {
       int a;
       scanf("%d", &a);
     }
     free(ptr1);
     free(ptr2);
     free(ptr3);
}
```

In the above program I get the address of the ptr as a difference 0f 10 between ptr1,ptr2,ptr3 instead of the difference 4 bytes. Also I'm checking the stack corruption here. How does the values in the data segment (ptr1,ptr2,ptr3), corrupts the value in the stack segment(a) here. And what is this silent corruption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`malloc` is required to give you the amount of bytes you requested (or NULL, obviously) but there is no rule against giving you *more.* It typically works on (for example) 16-byte (`0x10`) boundaries to efficiently allocate memory.

That's not to say you're allowed to *use* more than what you asked for, that's undefined behaviour (UB).

In other words, this is not allowed:

```
int *ptr1 = malloc (2);
*(ptr1+3) = 0xbeee;
```

since an integer must be at least the size of a byte/character so there's no way two bytes can give you four integers.

So, even if your integers *were* two bytes long (and they're probably not nowadays), this statement is trying to set the *fourth* integer in that array to a value. Think of it this way (for four-byte integers):

```
        +---------------+
ptr1 -> | You can use   | \
        | these 2 bytes.|  \
         ---------------    *ptr1
        | But not these |  /
        | two.          | /
         ---------------
        |               | \
        |               |  \*(ptr1+1)
        |               |  /
        |               | /
        | Nor any of    | \
        | these         |  \*(ptr1+2)
        |               |  /
        |               | /
        |               | \
        |               |  \*(ptr1+3)
        |               |  /
        |               | /
        +---------------+
ptr2 -> |               |
```

It's actually very unusual (and rather bad practice) to use magic numbers in code, a preferable solution would be:

```
int *ptr1 = malloc (sizeof (*ptr1) * N);
```

to get an array of `N` elements of your given data type.

As to *why* you see certain things happening, it really doesn't matter. Once you get into UB territory, all bets are off. *Anything* can happen, from things working as expected to a naked singularity forming inside your CPU which end up swallowing the Earth.

Bottom line, don't do it :-)

Comment: +1 just for the ascii art (woot!). (and of course for a valid answer).

Answer (score 3):

```
int *ptr1 = malloc ( 2 );
```

You are allocating 2 bytes for an `int`, which is normally at least 4 bytes in modern machine.

```
*(ptr1+2) = 0xabcd;
```

Pointer arithmetic is only valid if they are pointing to elements of an array or one past it, otherwise it's undefined behavior, as it is here.

Comment: I see heap corruption. Is there stack corruption too?

Comment: @CharlieBurns not that I see, but the code in the "silent corruption" block is clearly stepping out of range. The one I don't think the OP expected was the one Yu mentioned here, and a quick check of `sizeof(int)` will in all likelihood confirm it.

Comment: @WhozCraig the OP is asking stack corruption of "a". I just don't see it.

Comment: @CharlieBurns Once there's undefined behavior in your code, anything can happen.

Comment: @CharlieBurns Its not there, but by that time we're well into the land of undefined behavior, and if the heap is hosed (and it is), and `scanf()` uses the heap (which it *may*), who knows what will come out of this.